# What is JavaMail Folder type 3?

Tags: java, imap, jakarta-mail

I know that JavaMail knows the following types of IMAP folders:

Folder.HOLDS_MESSAGES (which equals the constant 1)
and
Folder.HOLDS_FOLDERS (which equals the constant 2).

So, today I did:

```
int type = folder.getType();
```

on a folder called "Drafts", which should be type 2.

But the variable type contains the value 3, which does not seem to be documented anywhere.

What does type 3 mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the ApiDoc [Folder.getType](http://java.sun.com/products/javamail/javadocs/javax/mail/Folder.html#getType%28%29):

> Returns the type of this Folder, that
>   is, whether this folder can hold
>   messages or subfolders or both. The
>   returned value is an integer bitfield
>   with the appropriate bits set.

So 3 is just the result of 2+1  in this case, which means your folder both HOLDS_MESSAGES and HOLDS_FOLDERS.

Remember: the int is a bitfield. You have to check it like this:

```
 if ((folder.getType() & Folder.HOLDS_FOLDERS) != 0)
```

etc, do not use `==` as operator.